# Can you compose parameterised types in Haskell type signatures?

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to write a custom Optics data structure that generalises Lenses, Prisms and Traversals. My data structure looks like this:

```
data Optic m a b = Optic { view :: a -> m b
                         , over :: a -> (b -> b) -> a
                         }
```

I want to write a function that composes two Optics, `optic1 :: Optic m a b` and `optic2 :: Optic n b c` to produce an Optic containing `view :: a -> m (n c)` and `over :: a -> (c -> c) -> a`.

In my head, the type of this composed Optic would be `Optic (m n) a c`, but this doesn't work - GHC will complain that m has one too many type arguments and n one too few.

Here's my non-compiling implementation of the compose function:

```
compose :: Optic m a b -> Optic n b c -> (m b -> (b -> n c) -> m (n c)) -> Optic (m n) a c
compose optic1 optic2 glue = Optic { view = viewCompose (view optic1) (view optic2) glue
                                   , over = overCompose (over optic1) (over optic2)
                                   }

viewCompose :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> n c) -> (m b -> (b -> n c) -> m (n c)) -> a -> m (n c)
viewCompose view1 view2 glue x = glue (view1 x) view2

overCompose :: (a -> (b -> b) -> a) -> (b -> (c -> c) -> b) -> a -> (c -> c) -> a
overCompose over1 over2 x f = over1 x (\y -> over2 y f)
```

The GHC error messages are:

```
optic.hs:7:83: error:
    • Expecting one fewer argument to ‘m n’
      Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘m n’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Optic’, namely ‘m n’
      In the type signature:
        compose :: Optic m a b
                   -> Optic n b c -> (m b -> (b -> n c) -> m (n c)) -> Optic (m n) a c

optic.hs:7:85: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘n’
      Expected a type, but ‘n’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the first argument of ‘m’, namely ‘n’
      In the first argument of ‘Optic’, namely ‘m n’
      In the type signature:
        compose :: Optic m a b
                   -> Optic n b c -> (m b -> (b -> n c) -> m (n c)) -> Optic (m n) a c
```

If I create an optic of type `Optic Maybe Int Int`, GHC understands that the first type argument has kind `* -> *` and doesn't complain about insufficient arguments. But I can't figure out how to combine types together to create another type of kind `* -> *`.

Is there any way (with or without language extensions) to express something like:

```
Optic (forall t. m (n t)) a c
```

Comment: Why without extensions?

Comment: Does it work if you use [`Compose`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose)? That is, `Optic (Compose m n) a c`.

Comment: `Compose` will make it `view :: a -> Compose m n c` rather than `view :: a -> m (n c)` as the OP requires.

Comment: I believe `Compose` is the closest you can get. Haskell does not allow type-level lambdas, since it assumes injectivity in many points during type inference, which is satisfied because we have _type names_ instead of _type functions_, roughly put (also see nominal vs structural types).

Comment: Thanks for the correction @FyodorSoikin — I completely missed that!

Answer (score 1):

As per @chi's comment, Haskell doesn't directly support type-level lambdas.  So, while there exists a type named `Maybe` of kind `* -> *` which directly represents the type-level lambda `\a ~> Maybe a`, there's no corresponding type directly representing the type-level lambda `\a ~> Maybe (Maybe a)`.

This means that given your defined type for the field `view`:

```
view :: a -> m b
```

it is impossible to find an optic `Optic m a b` for any type `m` that would satisfy:

```
view :: a -> Maybe (Maybe b)  -- impossible
```

You must instead use *some* kind of encoding for these types.  The `Compose` newtype imported from `Data.Functor.Compose` is one alternative.  It's definition is:

```
newtype Compose m n a = Compose (m (n a))
```

It basically wraps up the type lambda `\a ~> m (n a)` which has no direct Haskell representation into a type lambda `\a ~> (Compose m n) a` whose direct Haskell representation is simply `Compose m n : * -> *`.

The drawback is that it will introduce a non-uniformity in your types -- there'll be "plain" optics like `Optic Maybe Int Int` and then "composed" optics, like `Optic (Compose Maybe Maybe) Int Int`.  You can use `coerce` to work around this inconvenience in most cases.

The appropriate definition of `compose` using the `Compose` newtype would look something like:

```
type Glue m n b c = m b -> (b -> n c) -> m (n c)

compose :: Optic m a b -> Optic n b c -> Glue m n b c -> Optic (Compose m n) a c
compose optic1 optic2 glue
  = Optic { view = viewCompose (view optic1) (view optic2) glue
          , over = overCompose (over optic1) (over optic2)
          }
  where
    viewCompose view1 view2 glue x = Compose $ glue (view1 x) view2
    overCompose over1 over2 x f = over1 x (\y -> over2 y f)
```

and for a typical `Maybe`-based optic:

```
_Left :: Optic Maybe (Either a b) a
_Left = Optic v o
  where v (Left x) = Just x
        v (Right _) = Nothing
        o (Left x) f = Left (f x)
        o (Right y) _ = Right y
```

a composed optic might look like:

```
_Left2 = compose _Left _Left (flip fmap)
```

Using it directly will introduce a `Compose` wrapper:

```
> view _Left2 (Left (Left "xxx"))
Compose (Just (Just "xxx"))
```

but you can `coerce` the result to avoid explicit unwrapping, particularly helpful if there are multiple nested `Compose` layers:

```
λ> import Data.Coerce
λ> _Left4 = compose _Left2 _Left2 (flip fmap)
λ> :t _Left4
_Left4
  :: Optic
       (Compose (Compose Maybe Maybe) (Compose Maybe Maybe))
       (Either (Either (Either (Either c b4) b5) b6) b7)
       c
λ> view _Left4 (Left (Left (Left (Left True))))
Compose (Compose (Just (Just (Compose (Just (Just True))))))
λ> coerce $ view _Left4 (Left (Left (Left (Left True)))) :: Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe Bool)))
Just (Just (Just (Just True)))
```

The full code:

```
import Data.Coerce
import Data.Functor.Compose

data Optic m a b = Optic { view :: a -> m b
                         , over :: a -> (b -> b) -> a
                         }

type Glue m n b c = m b -> (b -> n c) -> m (n c)

compose :: Optic m a b -> Optic n b c -> Glue m n b c -> Optic (Compose m n) a c
compose optic1 optic2 glue
  = Optic { view = viewCompose (view optic1) (view optic2) glue
          , over = overCompose (over optic1) (over optic2)
          }
  where
    viewCompose view1 view2 glue x = Compose $ glue (view1 x) view2
    overCompose over1 over2 x f = over1 x (\y -> over2 y f)

_Left :: Optic Maybe (Either a b) a
_Left = Optic v o
  where v (Left x) = Just x
        v (Right _) = Nothing
        o (Left x) f = Left (f x)
        o (Right y) _ = Right y

_Left2 :: Optic (Compose Maybe Maybe) (Either (Either c b1) b2) c
_Left2 = compose _Left _Left (flip fmap)

_Left4 :: Optic (Compose (Compose Maybe Maybe) (Compose Maybe Maybe)) (Either (Either (Either (Either c b1) b2) b3) b4) c
_Left4 = compose _Left2 _Left2 (flip fmap)

main = do
  print $ view _Left4 (Left (Left (Left (Left True))))
  print $ (coerce $ view _Left4 (Left (Left (Left (Left True)))) :: Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe Bool))))
```